# Expand a slider only when a checkbox is checked and Animate for only once

Tags: manipulate, animation, slider

I have a random walk and I created a checkbox for the animation of the walk.

I want the checkbox to do the followings, but I have not found a solution yet:

- check the checkbox -> the slider of n gets expanded and the animation starts

Here is the MWE:

```
pts1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -10, 10}]
pts2 = Table[{x, 0.5*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {{Line[Take[pts1, n]],
    Line[Take[pts2, n]]
    }},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 100}}
  ],

 {{check, False}, {True, False}},

 {{n, 21}, 1, 21, 1,
  Animator, AnimationRunning -> check
  }]
```

Also, I really want the animation to run for only once. I tried

```
{{n, 21}, 1, 21, 1, AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
 Animator, AnimationRunning -> check
 }
```

but it seems to freeze the animation.

Anyone knows how to deal with the two problems?

Comment: `check the checkbox -> the slider of n gets expanded and the animation starts` I do not understand the above. As it is now, when I checked the box, it started running OK and the slider was moving. What difference do you want in this part? It seems to do this already. Or are you saying you do not want the slider to show up at all unless the check is checked?

Comment: @Nasser Yes. I want the slider to be hidden at first,  and to be shown only when I check the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the slider to be hidden at first, and to be shown only when I
>   check the checkbox

In this case I suggest you use `OpenerView`

[image]

### code

```
pts1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -10, 10}]
pts2 = Table[{x, 0.5*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}]

Manipulate[
 tick;

 g = Graphics[{{Line[Take[pts1, n]], Line[Take[pts2, n]]}}, 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 100}}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 200}];
 If[state == "auto" && n < max,
  n++;
  tick = Not[tick]
  ];
 Grid[{{Row[{"n = ", n}]}, {g}}]
 ,

 OpenerView[{"open",
   Grid[{{
      Row[{Button[
         Style["run", Small], {state = "auto"; If[n == max, n = 1]; 
          tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> {30, 30}],
        Button[
         Style["stop", Small], {state = "manual"; tick = Not[tick]}, 
         ImageSize -> {30, 30}]}]
      ,
      Row[{
        "n ", 
        Manipulator[
         Dynamic[n, {n = #; state = "manual"; 
            tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 21, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny]}
       ]}
     }, Spacings -> {1, 1}
    ]
   }]
 ,
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{state, "manual"}, None},
 {{n, 0}, None},
 {{max, 21}, None},
 ControlPlacement -> Above,
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

Comment: It's not what I initially expected but it works fairly well on my laptop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to nest `Manipulate`

```
pts1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -10, 10}];
pts2 = Table[{x, 0.5*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}];

Manipulate[
 If[check,
  Manipulate[
   Graphics[
    {Line[pts1[[1 ;; n]]], Line[pts2[[1 ;; n]]]},
    Axes -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 100}}],
   {{n, 21}, 1, 21, 1, Animator,
    AnimationRepetitions -> 2,
    AnimationRunning -> True},
   Paneled -> False],
  Graphics[
   {Line[pts1], Line[pts2]},
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 100}}]],
 {{check, False, "Enabled"}, {True, False}}]
```

Comment: It works for the MWE, but my Graphics contains a lot of other stuffs, so a nested Manipulate would not be applied well for me. Anyway, thanks for your advice!